# AJAX sending certain strings causes NullPointerException at request.getParameter()

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, jsp

I'm using AJAX to pass a string from a Javascript application to a Java server page (JSP) for processing. Here's a snippet of the AJAX code:

```
var toSend = new String.builder();
toSend.append('submission=').append(encodeURIComponent(submissionStr));
toSend.append('&currentQNum=1&haveNewResponse=true'
        + '&evaluate=').append(evaluate);
if (!isEmpty(selections)) toSend.append('&selections=').append(selections);
if (!isEmpty(rxnIds)) toSend.append('&rxnIds=').append(rxnIds);
callAJAX('answerframe.jsp', toSend.toString());

function callAJAX(url, toSend, method) {
    "use strict";
    xmlHttp.open('POST', url, true);
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    // set follow-up method when the server returns the page at URL
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = (!method ? updatePage : method);
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'message/x-jl-formresult');
    xmlHttp.send(toSend);
} // callAJAX()

function updatePage() {
    if (xmlHttp.readyState === 4) { // ready to continue
        var responsePage = xmlHttp.responseText;
        ....
```

In very rare (I've found two examples) but completely reproducible circumstances, certain values of submissionStr cause `xmlHttp.responseText` to come back empty. The log reveals that a NullPointerException is thrown at the second of the two lines from the JSP page:

```
Utils.alwaysPrint("answerJava.jsp.h: request is ",
        request == null ? "" : "not ", "null."); /**/
final String prefersJavaParam = request.getParameter("prefersJava");
```

The log output shows:

```
INFO: answerJava.jsp.h: request is not null.
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.GCTR.reset(GCTR.java:125)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.GCTR.doFinal(GCTR.java:116)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.GaloisCounterMode.doLastBlock(GaloisCounterMode.java:343)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.GaloisCounterMode.decryptFinal(GaloisCounterMode.java:511)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.finalNoPadding(CipherCore.java:1023)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:960)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(AESCipher.java:479)
    at javax.crypto.CipherSpi.bufferCrypt(CipherSpi.java:830)
    at javax.crypto.CipherSpi.engineDoFinal(CipherSpi.java:730)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2460)
    at sun.security.ssl.CipherBox.decrypt(CipherBox.java:535)
    at sun.security.ssl.EngineInputRecord.decrypt(EngineInputRecord.java:200)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:974)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readNetRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:907)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:781)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel.read(SecureNioChannel.java:362)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioBlockingSelector.read(NioBlockingSelector.java:159)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.read(NioSelectorPool.java:229)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.read(NioSelectorPool.java:210)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioInputBuffer.readSocket(InternalNioInputBuffer.java:643)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioInputBuffer.fill(InternalNioInputBuffer.java:945)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioInputBuffer$SocketInputBuffer.doRead(InternalNioInputBuffer.java:969)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.IdentityInputFilter.doRead(IdentityInputFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioInputBuffer.doRead(InternalNioInputBuffer.java:916)
    at org.apache.coyote.Request.doRead(Request.java:427)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.realReadBytes(InputBuffer.java:304)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.substract(ByteChunk.java:419)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.read(InputBuffer.java:327)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream.read(CoyoteInputStream.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.readPostBody(Request.java:2683)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParameters(Request.java:2636)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getParameter(Request.java:1106)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getParameter(RequestFacade.java:355)
    at org.apache.jsp.homework.answerframe_jsp._jspService(answerframe_jsp.java:409)
```

There are a number of features of this problem that are mystifying to me. Why would System.arraycopy() throw a NullPointerException at all, and why would it do so only when very particular values of `submission` are sent to the JSP page? Finally, what can I do to fix the problem?

Comment: It seems to be a [known bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8067755) marked as duplicate of [this one](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8049855) (which in turn is marked a duplicate of the first). Both list a workaround, one to disable AES/GCM ciper, the other to disable hotspot compilation using `-XX:CompileCommand=exclude,com/sun/crypto/provider/GCTR`.

Comment: Disabling the AES/GCM cipher solved the problem. Thanks!